# PING: transmit failed. General failure windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ping

i have problem which i could not figure it out how to fix it ,

i run in windows 8.1 connected with wifi .

when i open CMD and ping whatever address localhost, my router ip , 4.2.2.4 i get this respond :

```
C:\Users\raaaas>ping localhost

Pinging raas [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

but when i run cmd as admin i can ping everywhere !

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping localhost

```
Pinging raas [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

i had this problem on windows 8 and updated to 8.1 and for while i didnt had any problem until i dont know what happened .

my windows firewall is OFF , i dont have any ANTI-virus or other security tools , my system is clean . and funny thing is after connecting to game server my UDP connection drop too after 10 min ! and sometime my firefox can open youtube while my chrome cant establish any connection to any site !

Comment: I can confirm the error. In addition the problem only occurs when using the LAN interface but not when using WiFi.

Comment: If still significant, force using IPv4 as follows: `ping -4 localhost`. What output?

Comment: I do face the same problem in Windows 8 Pro - x64. Still, looking it ...